# How to embed m3u8 from ffmpeg Raspberry in Network Webserver

Tags: apache, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, http-live-streaming, rtsp

I have a Raspberry-Pi converting an RTSP-Stream to HLS-Segments via ffmpeg.
Now when I try to embed the Stream,

I use this:

```
<head>
<!-- CSS  -->
 <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<video id='hls-example'  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="400" height="300" controls>
    <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://192.168.2.45/files/hls/live.m3u8">
</video>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.14.1/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>
```

Working like a charm on the local raspberrypi apache2 Server.

Now the problem is, I cannot display this stream with the identical code on a seperate device.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a Firewallport I need to open?
I dont think so?
I can access the files when opening: http://192.168.2.45/files/hls/ on the seperate device.

Comment: Can you share the console from the browser on the other device - this will help people understand the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was Server-To-Server communication restriction. You need to enable this setting in the Apache Server file.
This setting is called CORS.